# r: lapply but with dynamic naming

Tags: r, list, lapply

Let's say I have 5 datasets in a list (each named `df_1`, `df_2`, and so on), each with a variable called `cons`. I'd like to execute a function over `cons` in each dataset in the list, and create a new variable whose name has the suffix of the corresponding dataset.

So in the end `df_1` will have a variable called something like `cons_1` and `df_2` will have a variable called `cons_2`. The problem I run into is the variable looping and trying to create dynamic names.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would be `do.call(rbind, List_o_DFs)` as a first step. Without a more concrete example, dunno that anyone can provide more specific ideas.

Comment: without a reproducible example, I can't provide an exact answer, but something like this will work: `myList <- lapplyseq_along(myList), function(i) within(myList[[i]][[paste0("cons_",i)]] <- somestuff(cons)}))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward:

```
df_names <- paste("df", 1:5, sep = "_")
cons_names <- paste("cons", 1:5, sep = "_")

for (i in 1:5) {
  # get the df from the current env by name
  df_i <- get(df_names[i])
  # do whatever you need to do and assign the result
  df_i[[cons_names[i]]] <- some_operation(df_i)
}
```

But it would make more sense to keep your data frames in a list to avoid using `get`, which can be sketchy:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  df_i[[cons_names[i]]] <- some_operation(df_list[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I need the resulting variable each to have a different name. My dataset is essentially the same 100 people rating 5 different movies, and the data is stacked rather than wide.

Comment: @vashts85 I see that I misunderstood your question. I'll clarify. But I still don't understand why you can't just have all your data frames in a list.

Comment: @vashts85 You should create a concrete example with reproducible input and desired output and add it to your question to avoid such misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the purrr package, this would be an alternative solution:

```
library(purrr)
lst <- list(mtcars_1 = mtcars,
            mtcars_2 = mtcars,
            mtcars_3 = mtcars,
            mtcars_4 = mtcars,
            mtcars_5 = mtcars)

map(seq_along(lst), function(x) {
lst[[x]][paste0("mpg_", x)] <- some_operation(lst[[x]]['mpg']); lst[[x]]
})
```

Subset each data frame from the list, create the new mpg variable with the index of the current data frame and perform whatever operation you want on the mpg variable. The result is a list with all data previous data frames with the new variable for each data frame.

Since this new list doesn't have the data frame names, you can always just add them with `setNames(newlist, names(lst))`